# Is there any significance to Chick's score overlay being slightly off?

Tags: cars

In the first race in [*Cars*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219) (2006) the racing commentators talk about the Piston Cup's three leading contestants. Meanwhile we're being shown a presumably in-universe camera view which contains a score overlay:

[image: First race score overlay]

For some reason, Chick's overlay is pointing slightly behind him. I always found this odd and I was wondering if there is any significance to this. Does this regularly happen in car race broadcasting? Or...

> ...considering Chick isn't really in to playing fair, could this suggest he is cheating in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there's any significance to this within the movie. I certainly don't believe it's evidence of Chick cheating - if the overlay positions are coming from telemetry data, for example, he'd want it to be positioned *in front of* where he is, not behind him.

By far the most likely explanation is that it's simply a mistake - Disney-Pixar either inserted it on purpose to make the coverage look more authentic, or they genuinely messed up. As for whether mistakes like that happen regularly in racing broadcasts: as a long-time Formula One enthusiast, I can confirm that they do. Take this example from the official F1 coverage of the 2018 Australian Grand Prix:

[image]

Comment: I remember this duel. I voted for Lastname as Driver of the Day after that!

Comment: This answer would be improved by the addition of some hand drawn circles.

Comment: @Darren I very much agree. I went ahead and added them.